# How to prevent a template class from being derived more than once?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following template class:

```
template<class I>
class T : public I
{
    // ...
};
```

This template class need to be derived once (and only once) for a given template parameter `I`.

```
class A : public T<U>  {};    // ok
class B : public T<V>  {};    // ok
class C : public T<U>  {};    // compile error
```

Template class `T` can be adapted to achieve such a behavior (while classes `A`, `B`, `U`, `V` cannot); however, `T` must not have any knowledge about derived classes `A`, `B`, `C`.

Is there any way to prevent such a template class from being derived more than once? Ideally issuing a compilation error in such a case or, at least, a linker error.

Comment: I don't see how you could do this without having some sort of registry of all classes in your program...

Comment: Whatever the solution is, it will involve a linker error. You can't do this with a compiler error, since each translation unit ignores that other translation units may instantiate.

Comment: @Dan : `T<I>` implements a mechanism that needs one single child class (cannot develop it here); I need some way to prevent `T<I>` from being derived twice, which would brake this mechanism.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : a linker error is not ideal but could make it, anyway; have a solution ?

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately even setting up such a registry could be a royal pain.  You would have to register all possible classes `X` from `A`, `B`, `C`, etc... and all possible types `Y` used to instantiate `T` (`U`, `V`, etc...) and then perform a big long search for search over `X * Y` combinations to detect any repeats.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have a solution in the form: class A : public X<U, A>  {};   (possibly where X<U, Base> inherits T<U> if it matters to have a T that does not depend on the derived class) ? That is, each of A, B, C that wants to inherit needs to specify itself as the template.

Comment: XY problem. If you think such a derivation will break something, demonstrate the breakage itself and ask how to avoid it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is possible if the base class `T` knows the types of its derived classes. This knowledge can be passed by CRTP or by an overloading tag to its constructor. Here's the latter case:

```
template<class I>
class T : public I
{
protected:
    template< class Derived >
    T( Derived * ) {
        static_assert ( std::is_base_of< T, Derived >::value,
            "Be honest and pass the derived this to T::T." );
```

Then, `T::T( Derived * )` needs to do something that will cause a problem if it has two specializations (with different `Derived`). Friend functions are great for that. Instantiate an auxiliary, non-member class depending on `<T, Derived>`, with a `friend` function that depends on `T` but not `Derived`.

```
        T_Derived_reservation< T, Derived >{};
    }
};
```

Here's the auxiliary class. (Its definition should come before `T`.) First, it needs a base class to allow ADL on `T_Derived_reservation< T, Derived >` to find a signature that doesn't mention `Derived`.

```
template< typename T >
class T_reservation {
protected:
    // Make the friend visible to the derived class by ADL.
    friend void reserve_compile_time( T_reservation );

    // Double-check at runtime to catch conflicts between TUs.
    void reserve_runtime( std::type_info const & derived ) {
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        static std::type_info const & proper_derived = derived;
        assert ( derived == proper_derived &&
            "Illegal inheritance from T." );
    #endif
    }
};

template< typename T, typename Derived >
struct T_Derived_reservation
    : T_reservation< T > {
    T_Derived_reservation() {
        reserve_compile_time( * this );
        this->reserve_runtime( typeid( Derived ) );
    }

    /* Conflicting derived classes within the translation unit
       will cause a multiple-definition error on reserve_compile_time. */
    friend void reserve_compile_time( T_reservation< T > ) {}
};
```

It would be nice to get a link error when two `.cpp` files declare different incompatible derived classes, but I can't prevent the linker from merging the inline functions. So, the `assert` will fire instead. (You can probably manage to declare all the derived classes in a header, and not worry about the `assert` firing.)

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045e8d56da5cc6f5).

---

You've edited to say that `T` cannot know its derived types. Well, there's nothing you can do at compile time, since that information is simply unavailable. If `T` is polymorphic, then you can observe the dynamic type to be the derived class `A` or `B`, but not in the constructor or destructor. If there's some other function reliably called by the derived class, you can hook into that:

```
template< typename I >
class T {
protected:
    virtual ~ T() = default;

    something_essential() {
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        static auto const & derived_type = typeid( * this );
        assert ( derived_type == typeid( * this ) &&
            "Illegal inheritance from T." );
    #endif
        // Do actual essential work.
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but isn't there a problem where your friend function breaks the ODR rule for inline functions by not having identical function bodies?  Though it's not impossible to work around if indeed that is the case.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yes, that's on purpose. The idea is to get the compiler to detect that ODR violation, but unfortunately I've not found a way to do so at link time. (If the ODR is violated within a single .cpp file, then it will be detected during template instantiation, which is the advantage of my first solution over the second.)

Comment: According to [**N4567 11.3/6-7**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) the friend function defined inside the class is automatically an inline function.  This means that it is perfectly OK to have multiple definitions, but it is UB for those definitions to differ and the compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic.

Comment: @GuyGreer Right, this answer doesn't reveal any compiler bugs. The `assert ( reserve( * this ) == typeid (Derived) )` line relies on UB to detect differing definitions of `reserve`. It's quite possible for it to fail, if the compiler inlines `reserve` more zealously. Perhaps it would be better to make `reserve` an empty function (so the definitions can never differ but multiple definitions per TU may be caught), and then do the runtime check as in the second solution.

Comment: @GuyGreer Updated with fixes. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Very elegant and efficient solution, working great either at link- or run-time. Thank you for your detailed and intelligible answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a big fan of macros but if using macros is not a problem to you - you could use a simple and compact solution as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class>
struct prohibit_double_inheritance { };

#define INHERIT(DERIVING, BASE) \
    template<> struct prohibit_double_inheritance<BASE> { };\
    struct DERIVING: BASE


template<class I>
struct T: I
{
    // ...
    static void do_something() {
        std::cout << "hurray hurray!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct U { };
struct V { };

INHERIT(A, T<U>) {
};

//INHERIT(B, T<U>) { // cause redetinition of the struct 
//};                 // prohibit_double_inheritance<T<U>> 

int main() {
    A::do_something();
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6OVLBGEXiux5Vn34)

Comment: Don't like very much macros but it's a working solution. Thanks.

Comment: @shrike I have exactly the same feeling about the approach

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that it's okay to pass `A`, `B` and `C` to `T` then how about this runtime solution?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <typeinfo>

//This class will check to see each T<X> is only instantiated with a unique Y
template <class X>
struct T_helper
{
    template <class Y>
    static void check()
    {
        if(derived_type)
            assert(*derived_type == typeid(Y));
        else
            derived_type = &typeid(Y);
    }
    static const std::type_info * derived_type;
};

template <class X>
const std::type_info * T_helper<X>::derived_type = nullptr;

template <class X, class Y>
struct T
{
    T()
    {
        T_helper<X>::template check<Y>();
    }
};

struct A : T<int, A> {};
struct B : T<int, B> {};

int main()
{
    A a1, a2, a3; // These are all okay
    B b1;         // This one will trigger the assert
}
```

Comment: Watch out for the race condition on `derived_type` in a multithreaded context.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well sure, this code is for expository purposes

Comment: Simple though efficient solution perfectly working at runtime. (Don't understand why it had not more upvotes.) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only answer I can envision is to have a registry of instantiations and their derivatives.  You could then devise a metafunction that searches the registry.  You pass it the base and the derived and if you're not deriving with the registered type it returns void type or something so it causes a compiler error.  Based on your requirements that the base has no knowledge of the derived this is the only remotely possible answer I can think of.

Your declarations would then look something like:

```
struct A : search_registry<T<U>, A>::type { ... };
```

I believe you're going to run into many issues that will be tough to solve even here--good luck!

And remember, template metaprograms are purely functional.  You can't "add" to the registry in any nice way.  You're going to need to define it once to hold everything.  On the plus side if someone forgets to add to the registry they'll know, or if they use a previously defined one...on the minus, this is ugly as duck.